# After Effects animation bodymovin.js: font issue, looks messed up

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, server

I have an after effects animation playing on a client's site.

Using: 
body.js
data.json

and the following code:

```
<script>
    $(".animation").click(function () {
        var anim;
        var elem = document.getElementById('bodymovin_overlay');
        var animData = {
            container: elem,
            renderer: 'svg',
            loop: false,
            autoplay: true,
            rendererSettings: {
                progressiveLoad: false
            },
            path: 'data_overlay.json'
        };
        anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animData);
    });
</script>
```

Everything was working fine but now we added a new animation file and all the font path's look odd (image attached).

View issue here: http://no11.ee/bringtest/

Any ideas for a solution and why this might be happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the player version 4.7.0 and your animation "data_overlay.json" is version 4.11.2
You'll need yo update the player as well.
https://github.com/bodymovin/bodymovin
Download the latest player from here or get the player from the extension itself.